# How to get the IP address of the newly created Azure VM via Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, ip-address, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to automate some processes in our project which includes some steps like  create the VM, connect to the newly created VM and run some commands remotely.

Now previously what I used to do is run this commands in sequence manually.

1.Create a VM

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name VmDeployment -ResourceGroupName XYZ`
  -TemplateFile "C:\Templates\template.json" `
  -TemplateParameterFile "C:\Templates\parameters.json"
```

2.Connect to the VM.

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value  100.9.4.12     
$UserName = "100.9.4.12\admin"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "admin@123" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Password)
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName 100.9.4.12 -Credential $psCred
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {Get-Service 'ServiceName'}
```

In this the IP address is used to add that in the trusted hosts on the client.I used to check the generated IP address on Azure Portal, replace that IP in the command and run them manually. But now , since I'm automating, there will be no manual intervention in the process.

So how should I retrieve the IP address of the newly created VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Powershell command to get all the private IP of the VMs. And the command will like this:

```
Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName resourceGroupName | Select-Object {$_.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress}
```

**Update**

Also the command to set a variable like this:

```
$vm = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName charles | Select-Object -Property  @{Name="Ip"; Expression = {$_.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress}}
$vm[0].Ip
```

Then you will only get the IP address.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The above cmdlet works. I have added -Name property as well. So it is specifically returning the Ip address for one machine. I want to assign this value to some variable and use that variable where ever required. So I have done this.

$vm = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName XYZ -Name VMName | Select-Object {$_.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress}

Now how do I access the variable.If I run $vm, it gives 
$_.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
------------------------------------
10.0.0.4

I just want 10.0.0.4

Answer (score 4):

Not directly related to your question, but have you thought about using Terraform to automate the creation of your resources? http://terraform.io

Terraform is very similar to ARM (only much nicer) here's an example of a VM creation and the public IP export:

```
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
      name     = "test-resources"
      location = "West US 2"
    }

    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
      name                = "test-network"
      address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
      location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
      resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
    }

    resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
      name                 = "internal"
      resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
      virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.main.name}"
      address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
    }

    resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {
      name                         = "test-public-ip"
      location                     = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
      resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
      public_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"

      tags {
        environment = "production"
      }
    }

    resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
      name                = "test-nic"
      location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
      resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"

      ip_configuration {
        name                          = "testconfiguration1"
        subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.internal.id}"
        private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id = "${azurerm_public_ip.test.id}"
      }
    }

    resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
      name                  = "test-vm"
      location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
      resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
      network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.main.id}"]
      vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

      # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM
      # delete_os_disk_on_termination = true


      # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM
      # delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

      storage_image_reference {
        publisher = "Canonical"
        offer     = "UbuntuServer"
        sku       = "16.04-LTS"
        version   = "latest"
      }

      storage_os_disk {
        name              = "myosdisk1"
        caching           = "ReadWrite"
        create_option     = "FromImage"
        managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
      }

      os_profile {
        computer_name  = "hostname"
        admin_username = "testadmin"
        admin_password = "Password1234!"
      }

      os_profile_linux_config {
        disable_password_authentication = false
      }

      tags {
          environment = "production"
      }
    }

    output "vm-ip" {
        value = "${azurerm_public_ip.test.ip_address}"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The tool which we are using only understands Powershell scripts.

Comment: No problem at all. I just know from personal experience that scripting the creation of VMs in PS can get... Messy :(

Comment: Just needed a clarification. Can I run terraform scripts in Windows powershell?

Comment: Terraform runs using it's own executable. You could invoke this executable using powershell, yes. But terraform needs to be installed on the machine that's running the powershell and the terraform files have to be .tf files. You invoke terraform on a folder and it consumes all the tf files in that folder.

You can find an introduction here: https://www.terraform.io/intro/index.html

Comment: I sometimes feel like a shill for Terraform, but going from PowerShell to Terraform is a transformative experience. Our PowerShell scripts were messy, ad hoc beasts, while our Terraform code was neatly organized into reusable projects (with IDE support!) and simple to deploy.

Comment: That's the exact same experience I had with PowerShell scripts spinning out resources. It ended up being a bunch of if not exists statements. Terraform works through desired state, it spins up your resources and keeps it in it's desired state.

Answer (score 1):

why do you care about the ip address? just use dns name? you always know that one (since you define it when you create vm, at least you can do that). Another option is to output the ip address as part of the arm template.

or query the ip address in powershell:

```
Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName ‘HSG-ResourceGroup’ -Name ‘HSG-LinuxVM’ | Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry for not mentioning this before , Public IP address and DNS name is blank for these VMs because of security reasons. I will have to get the Private IP address only.

Comment: doesnt really matter, just change the cmdlet to get the nic, not publicip